# get filmorgaphy for a chosen company with IMDBPY

Tags: python, database, imdb, imdbpy

From the documentation i see that companies has only 'main' and don't have 'filmography' unlike persons, but are there a way to fetch movies for the chosen company? Maybe it's possible to see the list of 'Films in Production' and 'Past Film & Video'?
I try to populate the data for the company with related movies somehow, but 'main' stays an empty list.

I don't want to go through all the movies in the db in order to check if the company present there, as it seems to be very inefficient. I use 'http' access, as i don't need a data base copy locally.

```
my_company = ia.search_company('Walt Disney Pictures [US]')[0]
id = my_company.companyID
ia.get_company(id) # the only info i can get! 
ia.update(my_company)
ia.get_company_infoset()
my_company.infoset2keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the IMDb web site changed the information on a company page, and right now IMDbPY is no longer able to collect other information beside the company's name and country.

I have opened an issue to describe the problem: https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy/issues/198